# object does not belong to a list error when loading file using clientcontext

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-clientobject

I am trying to load a file and its properties in sharepoint

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File newFile = null;
newFile = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(relativeURL); 
ListItem item = updateFile.ListItemAllFields;
clientContext.Load(item, i => i.FieldValuesAsText, i=> i.ContentType  );
clientContext.Load(newFile , i => i.CheckOutType, i => i.ListItemAllFields);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

This throws `"object does not belong to a list"` error when the **library name** and the **content type name** of the file are same

Works fine otherwise

What is causing this issue?